# Typescript omit argument from generic function type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How to omit prop type from generic function?

```
declare function func1<T extends {...}>(params: {age: number, something: T, ...more}): string

declare function func2<FunctionType extends (...args: any) => any>(cb: FunctionType): FunctionType
const newFunction = func2(func1)  // returns same type as func1
newFunction<{...}>({something: {...}, age: ...}) // is valid, but age should not be valid
```

in `func2` how to remove property `age` from first argument of `FunctionType`?

I tried:

```
declare function func2<FunctionType extends (...args: any) => any>(cb: FunctionType): 
(params: Omit<Parameters<FunctionType>[0], 'age'>) => ReturnType<FunctionType>

const newFunction = func2(func1)  // This returns the new function type without age, but also without generics
newFunction<{...}>({...})   // the generic is no longer valid, bit is should be
```

This way I can remove the property `age`, but the return type is no longer generic. How I can keep it generic and omit the `age` from the first argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you need that generic for since you don't seem to use it, but this should do:

```js
declare function func2<P extends {}, R>(f: (params: P) => R)
   : (params: Omit<P, 'age'>) => R
```

Comment: It is just an example, I have more generics in my real situation... anyway... I can't understand how this works. Your return type is (params: Omit<P, 'age'>) => R, and there are no generics in that type, but actually it accepts generics. How?

Comment: `ReturnType` and `Parameters` have the limitations you identified regarding generics, so instead of inferring the entire callback, which has generics, and loosing those generics, I inferred the parameter `params` and the return type as `P` and `R` directly. And this, TS can wire correctly.

Comment: I have to be able to add property to the returned function (just like an object) like this: const cb = () => {...}; cb.something = ... But this does not work. Do you have any solution for this (except cb.prototype.something = ...)? Since I return (params: Omit<P, 'age'>) => R, it does not allow me to add properties to the function

Comment: Theoretically you could return `((params: Omit<P, "age">) => R) & { foo: bar }` but it doesn't seem to work unless you set the constraint of `P` to be `{age: number, something: unknown, ...more}` to match `func1`. I don't know why TS is restricting the variance as soon as we add that intersection, especially given it should only affect the return type. It would make for a good SO question.